# What's the meaning of 'almost watching'?

Tags: word-meaning

I was watching a [video](https://youtu.be/JuMdTVV2gZ0?t=147) from youtube. The video was on a hippo picking on a crocodile in a safari park. Tourists were attracted by the rare scene.

A woman noticed birds around murmured this:

> Look at all the birds over there. They are *almost* watching.

I know the meaning of 'almost' but I cannot make sense out of it with this sentence.

To me, there are only two choices for watching action: watch or not watch. What's the 'almost watching'?

Comment: I understand it like this: "Look at the birds over there. It's as if they are watching."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may have been a speech error. The woman may have meant to say, "Look at all the birds over there. It almost looks like they're watching."

Comment: Do you mean she was too much in a hurry and shortened the sentence she imagined in the improper way?

Answer (score 0):

"Almost" is used in this sentence as a way to express "they could watch, but are not (yet) watching", trying to express that the birds would watch, if the event was more exciting.

More examples:
"I am almost asleep."
"You are almost there."
"The speaker was boring, I was almost listening."